# Using class based components with lang=ts alongside lang=js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I have a vue project thats using class based components.
I want to have one component that uses js language and not typescript.

Vue complains I need a new loader, and I cannot figure out how to add it.

I am using vue-cli, I dont have a webpack.config.js but I do have a standard vue.config.js

With vue-cli inspect --plugins, I have the following plugins, including vue-loader

```
[
  'vue-loader',
  'define',
  'case-sensitive-paths',
  'friendly-errors',
  'html',
  'pwa',
  'preload',
  'prefetch',
  'copy',
  'fork-ts-checker'
]
```

Yet vue complains in components without `<script lang="ts">`:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (6:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import Component from 'vue-class-component';
| 
> @Component
| export default class TreeNavigation extends Vue {
```

Basically, I want to have `<script lang="ts">` alongside components with regular `<script><script> or <script lang="js">`

Comment: Are you trying to use `vue-class-component` in a `js` component?

Comment: @StevenB.
Yes. Would that be a problem?

Checking the docs of ```vue-class-component```, they show only js examples.

It stills errors the same if I import from ```vue-property-decorator```.

Comment: Hmm just a question.  I don't know the answer but it looks like an issue with `experimentalDecorators` config.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas @StevenB. I have checked for experimental decorators in tsconfig and its enabled, same as "allowJs": true . I will be digging this more and I will let you know if I find the culprit.

Comment: @StevenB. I need to add babel plugin(loader) with ```vue add babel``` . Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add babel plugin(loader) with `vue add babel`